# VC dimension of axis-aligned hyperplanes and their complements

Tags: learning-theory, vc-dimension

This is a problem of VC that I've been trying to solve. Any help is appreciated.

Let's assume hypothesis classes $H_{\mathit{init}}$ of initial segments over domain $X = \mathbb R$ and $H_{\mathit{decst}}$
of decisions stumps over domain $X = \mathbb R^2$ as follows:

\begin{align}
  H_{\mathit{init}} &= \{h_a \mid a ∈ \mathbb R\}, \text{ where } h_a(x) = [x ≤ a], \\
 H_{\mathit{decst}} &= \{h^i_a \mid a ∈ \mathbb R, i ∈ \{1, 2\}\}, \text{ where } h^i_a
(x_1, x_2) = [x_i ≤ a].
\end{align}
Also, we define the class of complements of $H$, denoted by $H_c$, with flipped labels of the functions in $H$:
$$
H^c = \{h^c
\mid h ∈ H\}, \text{ where }  h^c
(x) = 1 - h(x).
$$

Finally, $H^{cc} = H \cup H^c$ denotes closure of $H$ under complements.

I want to calculate the VC dimension of $H_{\mathit{init}},H_{\mathit{decst}},H_{\mathit{init}}^{cc},H_{\mathit{decst}}^{cc}$.

Also, I want to show that $VC(H) = VC(H^c)$ and $VC(H^{cc}) ≤ 2 · VC(H)$.

I am having difficulty wrapping my head around what are decision stumps and how complements work to find VC dimension. I feel decision stumps can shatter three points and have 3 as VC dimension probably because of 2-dimensional space.

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.  We're not looking for posts that consist solely of the statement of an exercise-style task.

Comment: What's the context where you encountered this problem?

Comment: @D.W. I am having difficulty wrapping my head around what are decision stumps and how does complements work to find VC dimension.

Comment: If you are not able to show that $VC(H) = VC(H^c)$, I doubt that you will be able to solve the rest of the exercise.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus So, I am extremely new to these concepts. I just learnt how to calculate VC dimensions. I am not much familiar with complements. I'd be glad for any help or support.

Comment: Let me repeat. Until you understand the definitions well enough to prove $VC(H) = VC(H^c)$, you won't be able to complete the exercise. The proof of $VC(H) = VC(H^c)$ is very easy, once you understand the definitions.

Comment: If $H$ consists of the constant zero function then $VC(H) = 0$ while $VC(H^{cc}) = 1$, so the inequality $VC(H^{cc}) \leq 2VC(H)$ is false in general. What definitely holds is $VC(H^{cc}) \leq 2VC(H)+1$, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30139814/940550); there might be a simpler argument in your case.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Thank you prof. So, I am understanding most of it. Just have a few gaps which I am trying to fill. Thanks for the reference. I did get a direction to think.

Comment: @brianoconner Did you manage to compose a solution?